# React update state with nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state

I have a form, and when I submit it i want to update the state. Right now only name and surname works. How with the function handleChange can I also update the address, which is nested object? Or do I need to write another function for this? 
Thanks for help

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        address: {
            street: '',
            city: '',
        },
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ 
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,   
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const {name, surname} = this.state;
    const { street, city} = this.state.address;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type='text'
          value={name} 
          name='name'
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type='text'
          value={surname} 
          name='surname'
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type='text'
          value={street}
          name='street' 
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type='text'
          value={city} 
          name='city'
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your code cannot update `name` and `surname` since there is no `name` attribute provided(but you expect this as `e.target.name`). can you actualize code snippet? what `name` do you suppose to have for field `address->city`?

Comment: Add a name to each input then check that name in `handleChange` to differentiate street and city from the other inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to write separate change handler for `address`. It will keep your code simple and easy to understand instead of adding unnecessary complexity to this simple method.

```
function handleAddressChange = e => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState(({ address }) => {
        address: {
            ...address,
            [name]: value
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have `name` attribute in your form elements, and then check for that name value to `setState`. So the `render()` method look like this

```
render() {
  const {name, surname} = this.state;
  const { street, city} = this.state.address;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type='text'
        name={name}
        value={name}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input type='text'
        name={surname}
        value={surname}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input type='text'
        name={street}
        value={street}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input type='text'
        name={city}
        value={city}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>
  );
}
```

and `handleChange()`

```
handleChange = e => {
  const name = e.target.name;
  if (name === 'city' || name === 'street') {
    this.setState({
      address: {
        ...state.address,
        [name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
};
```

the `...` is [ES6 Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), It's the cleanest way to update nested state in React.

Comment: It is very bad idea what happens tomorrow you add new property in `address` like `zipCode` / `state`. And what if you rename any property then you need to understand you are checking for property name in some method which is more error prone.

Comment: I think it's fine, you just need to add a check in `if (name === 'city' || name === 'street')` and add an `input` with `name`. But eventually, this is just the solution to his question and no more :)

Comment: Nope for now you may think this is okay but believe hard coding that property name is really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You just need access to street and city?  Just destructure the address first like this.

Change

```
const {name, surname} = this.state;
const { street, city} = this.state.address;
```

to

```
const {name, surname, address } = this.state;
const { street, city} = address;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that all of you have faced a similar task, but the whole point is to remake the original state. React is not focused on working with nested states.

```
this.state = {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    street: '',
    city: ''
}
```

Comment: Well that is not the original state, and recreating it is NOT the whole point.   How can we assume that there isn't a good reason to have a distinct address object in state?  Suppose s/he wants to pass the address to another component?  Using your flattened state object, s/he would either have to explicitly pass `street` and `city`, or pass the entire state.  OP is right to use de-structuring.  It is the textbook use-case in React.

Answer (score 0):

In case if the name is changed or further fields added in state, then we can use
below structure.

```
  const onChange = (e) => {
       const{name, value} = e.target;
       const {address} = {...this.state}
       if(this.state.hasOwnProperty(name)){
        // if it is true, it means outside property
          this.setState({...this.sate,[name]:value})
       }
       else if(address.hasOwnProperty(name)){
      // if true,It means inner field object i-e address
          this.setState({...this.state,address:{...address,[name]:value}})
    }
    }
```